# How to get the translation of the object in a globalize3 with fallback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, translation, globalize3

I wanna get the translation with fallback.
My method is not suitable:

1) Change locale(I18n.locale = :de)

2) Get translations(Place.find(:id))

3) ...

4) Not profit!

**UPDATE:**
I find solution!

```
  before_filter :set_locale

  def set_locale
    locale = params[:locale]
    if locale.present?
      I18n.locale = locale
    end
  end
```

Comment: show what have you tried.